# Connecting my database remotely to prometheus

Tags: mysql, connection, prometheus

Using mysqld_exporter from Prometheus, I can't connect the database to Prometheus. The only one that works is just the one on my localhost but I want it to connect to the database remotely. I even created a user for that database using it's IP-address and identified it with the password. Even when I change the prometheus.yml file to use the IP-address of the database still nothing works. What can I do to connect the database?

Comment: Make sure you have configure mysql to allow remote connections..

Comment: You have to run this script in order to allow mysql accept remote connections GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' with grant option;